# I have nominated myself to become a moderator; you can do the same

Tags: discussion, election

Moderators work as a team, and it would be great to have a team that is diverse, has broad combined chemistry expertise, and broad combined social skills. I just self-nominated for the 2022 moderator election, and I would like to encourage others "in my cohort" to do the same. My chemistry focus is a bit on the edge of things, i.e. biochemistry. So if you have been on the site for three to six years and feel you could contribute, why don't you self-nominate? If you have someone in mind who might enhance your experience on the site if they were moderator, you could add this as a comment or as an answer. I know this is a bit pushy, but without more candidates than open positions, there can be no [election](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).

Comment: @Poutnik I enjoy your non-English-speaker insights, and the way you encourage new people on the site to ask well-researched questions.

Comment: @theorist I think you have a cool user name, and solid answers to show your expertise in that area.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne You know much more organic chemistry than I could ever hope to, and write very careful answers.

Comment: @andrew I have enjoyed bouncing off ideas when we happen to answer the same questions, sometimes with very different approaches. I have also learned quite a bit of physical chemistry from you.

Comment: @AChem I enjoy your history-of-chemistry take on questions, and your expertise in analytical chemistry.

Comment: You can't ping people like that https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/pinging-in-comment-to-suggest-answering-question

Comment: Also actual chemistry knowledge / experience isn't all that important as far as moderation is concerned.

Comment: related https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/wheres-ron-and-klaus-warzecha-for-the-election

Comment: Can I hijack this post in a more of a call to action way for the election? Would you be okay with this?

Comment: @Martin I was hoping that the post would open a wider discussion either here or in the election chat room. So yes, please hijack away.

Comment: As to my apparent lack of interest in nomenclature, my principal interests lie elsewhere as the record will show. I leave the bulk of nomenclature issues to those inspired by them.

Comment: @user55119 My comment was ambiguous, I removed it. I looked at your record (again, more carefully) and see that you have highly rated answers in various areas of organic chemistry, which is a great contribution to this site.

Answer (score 10):

> So if you have been on the site for three to six years

For what it's worth, I had been on SE for about a year when I was elected. The reader can form their own opinion as to whether that was a good or bad thing...!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think replicating what we already have is necessarily what we need, but if you want to look at exemplary models of moderation look no further than my fellow mods. Consider for instance @andselisk, who shows a stout devotion and does not shirk from any of the many moderation roles, from handling rude and abusive participants elegantly to editing posts, flagging low quality work, and commenting as necessary. Also on display are an impressive depth of chemistry knowledge and skill using moderation tools to identify and handle fraudulent use of the site. I'm glad to be in good company.

There are surely a good number of participants on the site who would make good mods, bringing their own range of skills and interests to the role. Karsten listed some in comments, who already make great contributions but may want to take on a different role as moderators. I also hope to see more apply to take on the position and encourage you to do so.